# Как правильно добавить агрегатную колонку к сущности в cycle orm?

Tags: php, orm

Есть две сущности: Игра и Разработчик, между которыми есть свзять типа многие ко многим, как описать схему для орм так, что бы сущность Developer имела агрегатную колонку countGames в которую бы мапилось количество игр данного разработчика.